# Ubuntu 20 : Ubuntu doesn't reconnect to WiFi unless I reboot

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, network-manager

I am dual-booting my laptop going between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20 LTS. Initially, I can connect to WiFi, but if I get disconnected for some reason, or if I restart my router, Ubuntu won't reconnect unless I reboot my laptop. Just logging out and back in won't work, I have to restart ubuntu, why and how can I fix this?

I previously had Ubuntu 18 and everything worked fine. Even when Im booted on windows, my wifi connection is up and running absolutely okay.

This is the output of nmcli :

```
    Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac"
    wifi (rtw_pci), DC:A2:66:80:A1:A7, hw, mtu 1500
    ip4 default
    inet4 192.168.1.12/24
    route4 0.0.0.0/0
    route4 192.168.1.0/24
    route4 169.254.0.0/16
    inet6 fda8:f5ac:9c4d:4c00:2c9a:68e:3bc1:9f6e/64
    inet6 fda8:f5ac:9c4d:4c00:fe21:8a3e:3ac4:1da4/64
    inet6 fe80::a79:3ca6:c898:1d9b/64
    route6 fda8:f5ac:9c4d:4c00::/64
    route6 ff00::/8
    route6 fe80::/64
```

So, when I restart Ubuntu my wifi doesnt work and no available wifi networks are shown. If I boot windows and then come back on Ubuntu, the wifi works fine for that session. If I restart ubuntu again, my wifi stops working.

Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Rather the restarting Ubuntu, you can try just restarting the Wifi.
Right click on the WiFi icon at the top right-> turn off, then turn it back on again.

Does that help ?

Comment: That doesn't help. Thanks for the answer though :(